# Is this code still having a reference cycle?

Tags: ios, swift

I am watching a video on Swift by Sundel, where he gives some tips to write more elegant code.

Initially he had this:

```
// A view controller that currently captures 'self' weakly, in
// order to call a method on a 'productManager' property object:
class ProductViewController: UIViewController {
    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        buyButton.handler = { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }

            self.productManager.startCheckout(for: self.product)
        }
    }
}
```

He uses that `[weak self] in` and `guard let self ...` to avoid retain cycles, which is fine.

Then he creates this utility method:

```
// Introducing a 'combine' function for applying a value to
// any function or closure:
func combine<A, B>(
    _ value: A,
    with closure: @escaping (A) -> B
) -> () -> B {
    return { closure(value) }
}
```

And then he replaces the initial code with this:

```
// Using our new combine function:
class ProductViewController: UIViewController {
    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        buyButton.handler = combine(product,
            with: productManager.startCheckout
        )
    }
}
```

He mentions that because we don't refer to `product` or `productManager` using `self`, there is no more retain cycle, and the code is cleaner too.

I think he is wrong, and his code is same as:

```
buyButton.handler = combine(self.product,
    with: self.productManager.startCheckout
)
```

We use `self` implicitly, even if we don't write it.

I still think he has a retain cycle.

Please provide me an answer whether he is right or wrong. If he is indeed right, I'd appreciate some explanation why. I just can't see it how avoided the retain cycle with his updated code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your assessment is correct and the author is wrong. But you can test this in Xcode. Present a `ProductViewController`. Tap the "buy" button so the handler is called. Dismiss the `ProductViewController`. Now use Xcode's "Debug Memory Graph" feature and see if there are any instances of `ProductViewController` still in memory. Test with the original "weak self" version of the code and then the "improved" `combine` version of the code.

Comment: @HangarRash - I've checked and there’s no strong reference cycle. Wasn't obvious at first glance. Thanks for you input too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no strong reference cycle. What `combine` receives is a strong reference to the product passed to it as an argument to its `value` parameter. `combine` has no idea where we got this product from (whether it came from an immediate expression, local variable, instance variable, …). It has no knowledge of the `ProductViewController`, let alone a strong reference to one of its instances.

> We use `self` implicitly, even if we don't write it.

Correct, depending on what *exactly* you mean by “use”. We use the strong (implicit) reference to `self` to lookup the `product` instance variable in the current object. Once we have a reference to the product, we pass it as an argument to `combine`’s parameter, and that’s the end of that

The problem would be if we created a new long-lasting strong reference to `self`, and stored it somewhere where it would complete a cycle.

Likewise, everything here also applies to the `productManager` and the capture of its instance method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was assuming combine has is an utility method in inside ProductViewController, therefore the issue. I suppose there is no issue if it's declared as a global function.

Comment: I've checked and as you said there’s no strong reference cycle. Thanks. I just never came across with such solution before and it wasn't obvious at first glance.

Comment: @ppalancica even if `combine` were an instance method of this VC, that still wouldn’t be an issue. The method would be invoked and return immediately, with no new persisted strong references to `self`.